# Get the aggregate size of nested object

Tags: javascript, nested, aggregate

I have the following JS object:

```js
[
  {
    title: "cat1",
    children: [
      {
        title: "Monday",
        children: [
          { title: "size1", size: 120 },
          { title: "size2", size: 75 },
          { title: "size3", size: 45 }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Tuesday",
        children: [
          { title: "size1", size: 105 },
          { title: "size2", size: 45 },
          { title: "size3", size: 75 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "cat2",
    children: [
      {
        title: "Monday",
        children: [
          { title: "size1", size: 60 },
          { title: "size2", size: 40 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

and want to evaluate the aggregate of the size in each nest. Say I will get

```js
[
  {
    title: "cat1",
    size: 465,
    children: [
      {
        title: "Monday",
        size: 240
      },
      {
        title: "Tuesday",
        size: 225
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "cat2",
    size: 200,
    children: [
      {
        title: "Monday",
        size: 200
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

So far I have the following code, but it doesn't work if the nest is two or more. I guess it's because of something related to "call by reference" but not sure how to fix it. Could anyone give me a help?

```js
const getFrequency = (item: any) => {
    console.log(item);
    if (item[0].children[0].children === undefined) {
      item.map((item2: any) => ({
        title: item2.title,
        size: item2.children.reduce((prev: number, curr: any) => prev + curr.size, 0)
      }));
    } else {
      item.map((item2: any) => ({
        title: item2.title,
        children: item2.children,
        size: getFrequency(item2.children)
      }));
    }
    return item;
  };

const freqData = getFrequency(nestedData);
```

EDIT: It has to be capable of recursively processing data with more than two nests.

Comment: what do you mean with "*nest is two or more*" do you have an example for this?

Comment: I mean it works if the data is only one nest, in this case only the "Day of Week" array (does not include "category").

Comment: If more nested depth is expected, then you might want to show it in your sample.  It sounds like a simple extra requirement, but it makes it a more difficult challenge.  Anyway, I've seen it done via recursion.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [{
    title: "cat1",
    size: 465,
    children: [{
        title: "Monday",
        size: 240
      },
      {
        title: "Tuesday",
        size: 225
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "cat2",
    size: 200,
    children: [{
      title: "Monday",
      size: 200
    }]
  }
];

arr.map(el => {
  const childSize = el.children.reduce((acc, item) => acc += item.size, 0);

  return { ...el,
    size: childSize
  }
});

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Okay I didn't mention it explicitly. It has to be capable of dealing with recursively, meaning that it can process data with more than two nests.

Comment: you can play with flat and flatMap js methods